# Remove the end of string after date

Tags: r, string, gsub

I actually have that:

```
a <- "Submitted 28 March, 2022;        originally announced March 2022."
```

But I only want to have the date, so:  `"28 March, 2022"` or that `"Submitted 28 March, 2022"`

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `parsedate` package:

```r
a <- "Submitted 28 March, 2022; originally announced March 2022."
parsedate::parse_date(a)
# "2022-03-28 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
gsub(";.*", "", a)
```

> "Submitted 28 March, 2022"

Or `gsub("Submitted |;.*", "", a)`

> "28 March, 2022"